# ffmpeg video rotation

Tags: ffmpeg

Im using ffmpeg (version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1) to input a rather long security video and turn it into a very sped up timelapse video.  Everything works perfect, except the resulting video is upside down, and I cannot figure out why or how to output it rightside up.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -vf framestep=60,setpts=N/30/TB -r 30 -an fastoutput.mp4
```

I have tried all sorts of `-vf "hflip,vflip"` and `-noautorotate` and it seems that everything I do winds up with a really nice video exactly as I want it except upside down from the input video.  What am I doing wrong?

Yes, I see the rotate lines in the output below, but I seem unable to turn them off!

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.11-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/media/WD_USB/timelapse/2022-08-12/concatVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 10:22:53.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2057 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2036 kb/s, 17.90 fps, 100 tbr, 90k tbn, 26 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 180
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 17 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x564596e4afe0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x564596e4afe0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x564596e4afe0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x564596e4afe0] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/media/WD_USB/timelapse/2022-08-12/fastout6.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libx264
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
      displaymatrix: rotation of -180.00 degrees
```

Comment: Related: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/8329

Comment: Seems like probably something with the metadata from the source stream or a bug in ffmpeg  … Probably try `rotate=180` and see if it helps.

Comment: The ticket #8329 you pointed to seems to be the issue, no matter what rotation metadata I tell it to add, it comes out upside down.  Apparently no one has fixed this bug in over 2 years.  Sigh.  Off to Openshot to edit the video manually, which sux, means I cant automate the video generation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like :
`ffmpeg -noautorotate -i inputfile.mp4 -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -vf framestep=60,setpts=N/30/TB -r 30 -an fastoutput.mp4`

Comment: thanks, and I just tried the command you posted twice, once with "rotate=0" and once again with "rotate=180" and it produced no difference in the output.  So I am leaning more and more to the ticket 8329 Raffa posted as being the source of my problem.

Comment: As a workaround you can try with [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) : `exiftool -Composite:Rotation=0 inputfile.mp4`. You can append `-overwrite_original` to modify file directly. You can also modify all files in the working directory : `exiftool -Composite:Rotation=0 -ext mp4 .`